# Why does the sum of basis of the column space and the basis of null space yield a zero column

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, orthogonality

We are given a column space that contains $a_1=[1,2,-3]^T$ and $a_2=[2,-3,5]^T$, and the null space contains $n_1=[1,1,1]^T$.

We are asked to form a matrix with the properties given above. In the solution, it is said because $n_1=[1,1,1]^T$ is in the null space, then we can set $a_1$ and $a_2$ as the first two columns of the matrix (they are linearly independent); and for the third column, have we must have $a_1+a_2+a_3=0$, where $a_3$ is the unknown column to be found. The found matrix is given as:

A=\begin{bmatrix}
1& 2 & -3\\
2 & -3 & 1\\
-3 & 5 & -2
\end{bmatrix}

I do not understand why we have such a relationship that helps us to find the third column.

Any explanation is appreciated.

Comment: What does null space mean? If $A\times(1,1,1)^T=0$, then ...

Comment: @Fshirke I got the point now! Thanks!